# Unable to delete EXE after it crashes even though process not shown in Task Manager

Tags: c++, windows, crash, delete-file, nmake

I have a program that I have written that crashes and I'm in the process of debugging it.

However, the issue is that when I attempt to create a new build, very frequently (but not always!) I get the message:

```
Cannot open file 'TheExecutable.exe'
```

I am then unable to delete, rename, move, or in any way modify the executable until the system is rebooted. Attempting to do so in Windows explorer gives

```
The action can't be completed because the file is open in TheExecutable.exe Close the file and try again.
```

This behavior isn't unique to the particular crash I'm dealing with right now, nor the particular program. Development is becoming a headache as every attempt to debug will now take several minutes to reboot and bring all my tooling back up.

**What, if anything, can I do to prevent Windows from "locking" the executable in such a fashion?**

No running process for that executable is visible in Task Manager

Full details of build system:

- Windows 10
- Intel Compiler, 19.1.0.166 Build 20191121
- nmake
- C++14

Comment: Why not kill the application using the Task Manager?  It sounds like the program has not crashed, but is in some sort of infinite loop / deadlock.

Comment: Open the task manager and see if the process is still in there.  Sometimes a segfault will leave a zombie in it's place.

Comment: Probably still open in the dubugger (even if it's not the active window).  Try clicking stop-debugging.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've confirmed the task is in fact not running in Task Manager, and this occurs even when I haven't attached a debugger.

Comment: try using [pskill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pskill) like `pskill TheExecutable` and see if that helps.

Comment: @NathanOliver Restarting the program has it show up in Task Manager, and I can kill it with pskill. Otherwise, the program isn't under Task manager and `pskill` gives `Unable to kill process TheExecutable.exe: Access is denied`.

Interestingly this is different than `pskill somefakeprogram.exe` which returns `...Process does not exist.`

Comment: ...but running Powershell as Admin allows me to kill it! If you answer with your suggestion, @NathanOliver, I'll be happy to award you the correct answer :)

Comment: It's really quite rare for a process not to show up in Task Manager.  Make sure you're looking at the processes list (the tab is named "Details") and not the task list (on a tab inaccurately named "Processes").  And that you've selected "Show processes from all users".  Then you can see everything including critical system processes.  The only reason for a process not to show up there would be a rootkit (or simply not being a process at all, for example a device driver).

Comment: Yes, I was under "Processes" and even expanded the Windows PowerShell listing to show the exe's (if any) running in that PS session. It would appear while running, crash, and disappear. Strange (and obnoxious) behavior.

Comment: hey i experiencing the same thing under Win 7 using VStudio 2015,... why the locking mechanism is still occured.... what is the solution for this matter ? 
If i exit the VStudio and wait after 2 minutes then the Debug can be deleted... 

But if i just wait 2 minute but still using VStudio, the debug\app.exe inside unable to be deleted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your process is not being terminated all the way.  Since it is not list in the task manager, you can use [PSKILL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pskill) to end it manually.

Open power shell or the console in administrator mode and run

```
pskill name_of_executable
```

and it should terminate it so you can re-run it.

Comment: let me try this first.... i'm wondering is this same as taskkill ?